# How to configure a listening-only NTP client?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, time, kiosk, busybox

I'm creating an advertisement display, based on *RaspberryPi* (no real time clock present) and *[piCore](http://tinycorelinux.net/ports.html)*, which is *busybox*-based tinycorelinux. It will be behind a firewall, and even within its own network segment it should never make an outgoing connection, but only receive stuff, like a picture to display (via VNC listening client) or **current datetime**. It is not known in advance, what host(s) will send stuff; luckily, everything from own segment is okay to accept.

So polling pool.ntp.org is obviously not an option. According to ntpd(8), "**ntpd** can operate in any of several modes, including symmetric active/**passive**".

- Is it possible to start ntpd in way that it sends no requests but accepts (S)NTP packets?
- If not ntpd, anything else? (possibly from RaspberryPi / busybox repertoire)
- Hosts sending stuff to my RaspberryPi are Windows10 PCs. I cannot install programms there, but only run portable stuff. My plan is to write a script to  write the (S)NTP packet content into a file and then send it with [packetsender](https://packetsender.com/documentation). Any simpler ways?

Comment: That's an odd security policy. Outgoing packets even within subnet are bad, but accepting any garbage from the same subnet is okay?

Comment: @grawity, that's not really a policy. All devices in the segement trust each other. However, at development time, nothing is known about the deployment environment and I do not want that users have to configure anything on RasPi. They will just add RasPis to listeners list on the host which sends pictures.

Comment: Perhaps multicast-NTP would be suitable then.